# how to compile typescript with react definitions

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I am trying to write a typescript module which make use of `React.addons.update`. However, I couldn't find a way to make it compile.

I have a folder with the following files:

- https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react/react.d.ts
- test.ts containing:

  ```
  /// <reference path="react.d.ts"/>
  React.addons.update({}, {test : {$set : "foo" }});
  ```

I run the following commands:

```
node <pathtotsc>\tsc -v
=> message TS6029: Version 1.3.0.0

node <pathtotsc>\tsc react.d.ts test.ts
=> test.ts(2,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.
```

What I am missing? How to reference correctly the react definition?

**edit**

```
node <pathtotsc>\tsc test.ts
test.ts(2,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'React'.
```

Answer (score 3):

The relevant information can be found [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files). The trick is to "reverse" the explanation to understand how a definition file is meant to be consumed.

In this case, react.d.ts shoud be used like this:

```
/// <reference path="react.d.ts"/>
import React = require("react/addons");
React.addons.update({}, {$set : "foo" });
```

Sadly, this require the module compilation flag for tsc, which I don't want to use (I want static only compilation). The solution is to either use modules, or add a line like at the end of the definition file:

```
declare var React : AddonsExports
```

This works, but sadly the interface declaration for `update` is incorrect, so I cannot use it even with this modification.

Answer (score 1):

As of Jan. 14, 2016, with React 0.14.3 and Typescript 1.6.2, the following d.ts import finally made Typescript recognize `React` and `ReactDom`in ts files.

`tsd install react-global --save
tsd update --save --overwrite`

I must have used an old tutorial originally.  It said I only needed the `react.d.ts` file.  But since then, it seems that newer versions of React require more definition files.

Installing `react-global` added all these files to my tsd.d.ts:

`/// <reference path="react/react-dom.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-create-fragment.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-css-transition-group.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-linked-state-mixin.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-perf.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-pure-render-mixin.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-test-utils.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-transition-group.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-addons-update.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="react/react-global.d.ts" />`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `react-addons.d.ts` file (available on NuGet or via Definitely Typed).

```
/// <reference path="scripts/typings/react-addons/react-addons.d.ts" />

React.addons.update({}, { test: { $set: "foo" } });
```